# Partitioning the set of vertices of a convex n-gon into nonintersecting polygons

Tags: co.combinatorics

How can you prove that
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{2k-2} (-1)^r \binom{2k-2}{r} (5k-2-r)^{2k-2} =(2k-2)!
$$
This result I have obtained by comparing results of two different approaches for the partitioning of the set of vertices of a convex n-gon into nonintersecting polygons.

Comment: In Mathematica, one can check for specific k: With[{k = 7},
 {Sum[(-1)^r Binomial[2 k - 2, r] (5 k - 2 - r)^(2 k - 2), {r, 0, 
    2 k - 2}]
  , (2 k - 2)!
  }]

Comment: Along the same lines as https://mathoverflow.net/q/417106

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that more generally
$$
\nabla^{2k-2}[x^{2k-2}](x) = \sum_{r=0}^{2k-2}(-1)^r\binom{2k-2}{r}(x-r)^{2k-2}
$$
is the order-$(2k-2)$ [backwards finite difference operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences) acting on the monomial $x^{2k-2}$, which is the constant $(2k-2)!$.

Comment: @ Timothy Budd -This approach is really interesting and very quick. I think here you have to find 2k-2 nd backwards difference   ( which I did in my research to derive general formula) and differentiate the function 2k-2 times then equal the coefficient of the highest power ot n .